# changing and hiding parts of a table

Tags: jquery, replace, format, hide

I've got a html table with td class-formlabel and text (HP)Hello

1. Why doesn't this replace the text?

   ```
   $(this).text().replace('(HP)','');
   ```
2. Why does this remove formating if `this` is `$("td.ms-formlabel").each(function(){`

   ```
   $(this).text("hello");
   ```
3. How can hide the TR rows for a match given the rendered html above and the below code? (Note I need to use the below condition and loop)

   ```
   $("td.ms-formlabel").each(function(){

   if($(this).text().match('(HP)')){
      // what code here to hide the entire TR row ?
   }
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$(this).text().replace('(HP)','');` does replace the text, but you don't do anything with it - try:

   ```
   var text = $(this).text().replace('(HP)','');
   $(this).text(text);
   ```
2. It shouldn't remove and formatting unless you're applying it with tags inside`.ms-formlabel`

   ```
   <td class="ms-formlabel"><b>Bold</b></td>
   ```

   will become

   ```
   <td class="ms-formlabel">Hello</td>
   ```
3. You can use:

   ```
   $(this).closest('tr').hide();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. `.text()` returns a string. To modify and replace the text, you have to set it back again. It's kind of the equivalent to the fact that `x + 5` doesn't change `x`. You have to type `x = x + 5` In this case, the code would be this:

   ```
   $(this).text($(this).text().replace('(HP)',''));
   ```
2. I don't quite understand this question. If you're trying to set some HTML styling, use the `.html()` function instead.
3. Try this:

   ```
   if ($(this).text().match('(HP)')) {
       $(this).closest('tr').hide();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- You should use `:contains`
- Text will strip formatting, you should use `.html()`
- To specify HTML (or text for that matter), you put the new content within the brackets, i.e. `element.text(content)`

So here is an example...

```
$("td.ms-formlabel:contains('(HP')").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace('(HP)',''));
    $this.closest('tr').hide();
}
```

I think that's what you want. The only thing that I might be wrong with is which row you want to hide... your wording is kind of confusing...